# tareas programadas laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Esto progamando unos reportes desde mysql con task scheduler de laravel, al momento tengo este

```
->dailyAt('15:35')->fridays()
```

el cual se envía un reporte los viernes a las 3:30, como hago para que también se envié los miercoles a las 8am el mismo reporte

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar el método **cron**. Puedes hacer pruebas y generar un patrón, por ejemplo, [Aquí](https://crontab.guru/#30_3_*_*_3,5)

En tu caso, sería ago así...

```
->cron('30 3 * * 3,5')
```

O si prefieres algo más parecido a lo que tenías, puedes usar

```
->weekly()->days([3,5])->at('3:30');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a validar según veo la hora es la misma para los dos dias, pero también me sirve.

Comment: Exacto... Ni me había dado cuenta. Pero es que si cada día es a una hora diferente, casi hablaríamos ya de dos tareas programadas, y no de una. Eso también podrías hacerlo: programar dos. Aunque personalmente recomendaría solo una. Normalmente los horarios sí pueden ser compatibles dependiendo del día de semana de unos días a otros.